# Search string which contains multiple words using CATSEARCH query in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

String record : Blueoba Mountain Company

SQL Query :

```
SELECT from table 
WHERE CATSEARCH(account_partner_name_type,'%Blueoba% %Mountain% %Company%', NULL) > 0) 
where rn <=500;
```

If I write the full name of the string in the query (i.e.%Blueoba% %Mountain% %Company%) then it gives me the record.

But if I write %Blueoba% %Mountain% %Comp% or %Blue% %Company% or %Comp% then its not returning any record.

So ideally, if I write a word %comp% then it should search all the records which contains 'comp' word and show the records but its not showing.

Can anybody suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using wild card characters

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE account_partner_name_type like '%Blueoba%'
and rn <=500;
```